# Who actually executes an HTTP request in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, http, networking, web, browser

Is this a web worker who actually executes an HTTP request and waits for server response?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, and the answer is internal to the implementation of each browser engine separately.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP requests are executed by the browser web APIs such as XMLHttpRequest. It is not an API provided by the JavaScript but an API provided by the browsers.

More Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest